# Disable flyspell-mode by default

Tags: spacemacs, flyspell

How do you disable `flyspell-mode` by default in spacemacs?

I don't see where it is enabled in the first place.

With `customize-variable` I can track down `global-flycheck-mode`, but they seem to be unrelated.

Every buffer I open underlines misspellings in red and if I `SPC SPC flyspell-mode` it reports "disabled" and they go away. This is my basis. I want them gone.

Comment: Check your init file: search for `spell`. You have probably added `spell-checking` as a layer. See https://www.spacemacs.org/layers/+checkers/spell-checking/README.html (Disclaimer: I know nothing about spacemacs).

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that, I do have the `spell-checking` layer, because otherwise I didn't have bindings for doing on-demand spell checks. I guess something about that layer activates `flyspell-mode` for all buffers, but I can't find which variable it's editing and how to overwrite it. That is the only relevant hit when searching for spell. The other hits are just flyspell packages.

Comment: Isn't each layer implemented through a config file? Have you looked at that config file?

Comment: Not sure, thanks for the tip, I'll have to look into that!

Comment: Okay! In `emacs.d/layers/+checkers/spell-checking/config.el` the first line sets `spell-checking-enable-by-default`. I changed that and it worked! Odd that I can't access that variable through `customize-variable`.

Comment: Do you want to put this into an answer?

Comment: No, I just threw out a couple of random suggestions. I'm glad they were helpful, but that does not an answer make. However, you should provide the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `emacs.d/layers/+checkers/spell-checking/config.el` the first line sets `spell-checking-enable-by-default` to `t`. At first I set this to `nil`, but I don't think setting it here is the most spacematic way of going about it.

What I did instead is add

```lisp
;; disable flyspell-mode
(setq-default spell-checking-enable-by-default nil)
```

to the `dotspacemacs/user-init` function in `.spacemacs`.

---

I first tried to add it to `dotspacemacs/user-config`, but it did not take effect. The fact that it works in `user-init` is not intuitive to me: since `user-init` is loaded "before layer configuration", I would think that `spell-checking-enable-by-default` is set to `nil` by `user-init`, then set back to `t` when `config.el` is run. It's also confusing because `config.el` calls `defvar`, which I understand to mean the variable `spell-checking-enable-by-default` is created and set in that `config.el`. If that's true, how can I set it before it's created, in `user-init`. If anyone can explain this in a comment that'd be great!

Any confirmation that this is the best practice is appreciated.

Comment: You can set this via the `:variables` keyword in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` as described in the spell-check layer its [documentation](https://develop.spacemacs.org/layers/+checkers/spell-checking/README.html#disabling-by-default). The `:variables:` can generally be used to set variables for configuring layers (and not only for layer specific variables).

Comment: As a 'side' comment, you can quickly jump to a layer's configuration file using `SPC h SPC`.