# How to selectively enable flyspell-mode?

Tags: spacemacs, spell-checking

How can I selectively enable spell checking?

Previously I had the same issue as [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/70037/disable-flyspell-mode-by-default) and disabled spell checking globally. But now I can't seem to enable it back on buffers that I need it, like org and latex.

I've tried adding `(flyspell-mode-on)` to the mode hooks, to no effect.

```lisp
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
            (lambda ()
              ;...
              (flyspell-mode-on)
              ;...
              ))
```

Calling it interactively on the buffer seems to work, though.

layer configuration:

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/layers ()
  "Layer configuration:
This function should only modify configuration layer settings."
  (setq-default
   ;...

   ;; List of configuration layers to load.
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(
     ;...
     (spell-checking :variables
                     spell-checking-enable-by-default nil
                     spell-checking-enable-auto-dictionary t)
))
```

I'm using spacemacs 0.999.0 (develop head) @ emacs 27.1

Comment: Can we talk there? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137376/togglingflyspell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc string of `flyspell-mode-on` says it all:

> Turn Flyspell mode on.  Do not use this; use ‘flyspell-mode’ instead.

The canonical way for switching Flyspell on in Orgmode is:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'flyspell-mode)
```

And if you want to use Flyspell with LaTeX you have to consider which exact mode you use. Do you use the built-in `latex-mode` or do you use the AucTeX version.

For AucTeX you have to set:

```el
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'flyspell-mode)
```

for the internal `latex-mode` you have to set

```el
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'flyspell-mode)
```

Comment: @Luctins I think it is time to delete your last comment. Afterwards I will delete this one.